# Setting up Sencha extjs project

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6-modern

I am attempting to set up a Sencha extjs 6 project. I would like to be able to have both the modern and classic packages available. I'm following this set-up [tutorial](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html), but am not finding it very helpful.

If my understanding is correct, I should be able to have one app that accessible as both a desktop and mobile site. This is great and works for the uncompiled path (my app is in the folder root/sencha) mysite.com/sencha. However, if access the root site it also gives me the uncompiled path instead of using the build app.js.

My index page is at `root/layouts/index.html`. My extjs app is in `root/sencha`.

The relevant parts of my app.json are:

```
...
"indexHtmlPath": "../layouts/index.html",
"production": {
    "output": {
        "page": {
            "path": "../../../../layouts/index.html",
            "enable": false
        },
        "appCache": {
            "enable": true,
            "path": "cache.appcache"
        },
        "microloader": {
            "path": "microloader.js",
            "embed": false,
            "enable": true
        }
    },
    "loader": {
        "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
    },
    "cache": {
        "enable": true
    },
    "compressor": {
        "type": "yui"
    }
},
"output": {
    "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
    "page": "index.html",
    "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
    "js": "${build.id}/app.js",
    "appCache": {
        "enable": false
    },
    "resources": {
        "path": "${build.id}/resources",
        "shared": "resources"
    }
},
...
```

Comment: Little bit confused from your Q but just run `sencha app build ` and copy the content of the build folder to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

As pagep suggested you just deploy on your production server the content of the build/production directory and not the source code. That way you only deploy the minimized and compressed files (classic/app.js, classic/resources/YourApp.css, modern/app.js, modern/resources/YourApp.css, etc...).